# Why do methods include strong-references to instances/classes?

Tags: python, python-2.7, methods

If you examine a method in python, you'll find the `im_class` & `im_self` attributes. If you look closer, you'll see that these are strong-references!

Maybe i'm alone in this; but the way i figure it, if methods themselves are dependent upon their respective class/instance (i.e., the `self` argument), then the method should "go down with its ship", no? Why would the authors choose to store *strong references* in the method objects instead of weak references? This forces users that want to avoid circular-referencing to use [workarounds](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/81253-weakmethod/). Does anyone have any use cases where strong referencing the class/instance is preferable?

Example:

```
from weakref import proxy

class Foo(object):
    def func(self):
        pass

>>> foo = Foo()
>>> func = foo.func
>>> _foo = proxy(foo)
>>> func.im_self is _foo
False
```

Comment: Perhaps it is because your writing style there assumes there's a problem. Further you make it sound like you're the only one who has discovered a big problem with Python. You write accusingly, instead of inquisitively.

Comment: @nneonneo: "*assumes there's a problem*"..."*accusingly*"...? Are you kidding me? Where is *any* of that coming from?

Comment: "Why would they do that? This forces people to do X!"

Comment: Also, if you "still haven't discovered what it is" that makes people assume you are hostile, and then you act hostile when I try to explain it (from my viewpoint, your writing really is somewhat aggressive!), I cannot really take you seriously.

Comment: @nneonneo:
"`Why would they do that?`" --Genuine
"`This forces people to do X`" -- Also genuine, but with no exclamation point.
Nomatter. I think i'm just going to add that disclaimer to all my questions from now on... :-\

Comment: @NoobSaibot: please don't add disclaimers; people will actively start looking for the issues you are then talking about. It's like asking everyone not to think about a hippo..

Comment: @NoobSaibot: I do agree with nneonneo here; your tone is one of disbelief that the developers haven't thought of this problem, with the unspoken addendum of *how stupid are they* hanging in the air. Instead, entertain the idea that perhaps you missed something.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: [I believe i was able to get to the bottom of it](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/18536064#18536064). At the end of the day, people will see what they want to see. All we can do is try to show them as best as we can.

Comment: @NoobSaibot glad you were! You received some good advice there. :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is only true of *method wrappers*, which are bound to a specific instance of a class. Using a strong reference avoids interesting surprises; for example, for a class `X`, `func = X().foo; func()` does what you'd expect (with a weak reference, the `X()` would be deleted and the subsequent `func()` call would fail unexpectedly).

If you want to have "weak referenced methods", the simplest way is just to pass around a tuple of (class method, weak instance), e.g. `(X.foo, weakref.ref(x))` instead of `x.foo`.

Comment: Thanks, @nneonneo. I've edited my post to include some code. What do you mean by "*method wrappers*"? Is this the `func = foo.func` object in my example?

Comment: Your code makes no sense. `foo.func()` returns None.